# Apache Flink WordCount Example - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/FlatMapFunction

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-flink, word-count

I followed [this guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html), but I get an Exception if I run WordCount from my IDE

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7536 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/marc/Programs/idea-IC-162.2032.8/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/marc/apache flink/flink.gelly/target/classes:/home/marc/Programs/idea-IC-162.2032.8/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain haw.bachelor.flink.gelly.WordCount
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/FlatMapFunction
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 3 more
```

my environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Oracle Java 8
- Maven 3.0.5
- intellij community edition

Answer (score 17):

here is what i changed setting and the error was gone
[image: here is what i changed]

Comment: Worked in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In Intellij IDEA (2020.3), the UI is a little different.

Steps:

1. Activate Run-Configuration dropdown
   [image: Activate run-configuration dropdown]
2. click `Edit Configurations...`
   [image: Edit Run Configuration]
3. click `Modify Options`
   [image: Select Modify Options]
4. select `include dependencies with "Provided" scope`
   [image: Select include dependencies with provided scope]
5. Click "done"

Flink sources should now be included, which should resolve the error encountered - it did for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in your IDE, you must select "mainRunner" instead of "root" from the "Run Configurations" menu. It makes the classpath load the classes that are "provided" in the project.

Comment: can you please share a screen shot how to do it in IntelliJ if you have time

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by deactivating 'build-jar' profile in Maven in the IDE. It seems that turning that off will enable run-time classes to be available.

Comment: can you please share a screent shot how to do in intellij Idea